# Editing Source Files in browser

Tags: browser

which browsers supports edit source file (js,html,css) option other than chrome?

I'm using chrome for overriding the source files in the browser. is any other browsers or any ways to do the same other than chrome?.

Comment: Im using firefox quantum updated version but i cant able to edit  javascript files there...@Lucas

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/) supports code inspection and manipulation as well as debugging and most development features found in Chromium.

Comment: I have checked with latest version but its not supported @Lucas.